# Is it possible to pass parameters hidden to html page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I want to pass username and password to a html page or url. For eg. consider www.gmail.com i want to pass username and password through javascript, jquery or any scripting such that it will not be visible to others and it has to login automatically without showing any parameters passed. Another doubt is if i keep the username and password in my script the user can able to view with using view source or debugging tool. is there any other way to pass but none can view it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you think you are "Programmer" and gmail and web is fool...

Comment: If i am a good programmer then why am i posting here. And i clearly stated that for example only i stated gmail I am not going to do the same on gmail. Anyway thanks for your comment great programmer

Comment: do you control the service you're logging in to?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not. The browser communicates with the server over HTTP and receives HTML and Javascript code, which it uses to Do Stuff.™ There is no third backdoor, it's all transparent to anyone who cares to look. It needs to be. It's an open standard.

Answer (score 3):

You could hash it, perhaps against some time value that would expire. Whatever you send can be seen, you can build your own browser if you wanted to. You can spoof user agent headers... Basically, you're just sending information at an address and they are sending some information back.
I wasn't clear about where you want to send from and to and who you wanted to hide the information from.